# Finding 4 numbers in a string bash script

Tags: bash

I need to check for the user ID  in a weird looking string.  I only want the lines that have it.  How do I check for 4 integers in a row in the following sample strings?

```
    "111/S/H0110//Jake, Greenfield ServiceRequest/bin/ksh"
    "740/S/H5155//Jake, Greenfield/bin/ksh"
    "90/S/Customer  /usr/bin/ksh"
    "740/S///Jake, Greenfield/bin/ksh"
```

In these examples I would want these lines to pass:

```
    111/S/H0110//Jake, Greenfield ServiceRequest/bin/ksh
    740/S/H5155//Jake, Greenfield/bin/ksh
```

and NOT these to pass:

```
    90/S/Customer  /usr/bin/ksh
    740/S///Jake, Greenfield/bin/ksh
```

## BONUS QUESTION

The ID can be anything from,

```
    [A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
    [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
    [A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

meaning, for example:

```
    7A7777
    AA7777
    A77777
    A-7777
```

(though I would settle for "just" finding "7777" in the string)

Comment: Do you need it to be bash?

Comment: I think he means it to be "in a script".  The tool to use is "sed(1)" or "awk(1)".  Read the man pages for constructing a regular expression that matches decimal numbers (or ID's) separated by things that are not numbers (or ID's).  hint:  "[^A-Za-z0-9]+" might be useful.

Comment: This should make it: `grep -E '[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}|[A-Z]-[0-9]{4}|[A-Z]-[0-9]{4}' file`.

Comment: yes I mean in a BASH script

Comment: @fedorqui I believe you have the right ans with :   grep -E '[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}|[A-Z]-[0-9]{4}'

Comment: @fedorqui  Reply to this  thread and I will vote yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in comments, this can make it:

```
grep -E '[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}|[A-Z]-[0-9]{4}'
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                (1)              (2)             (3)
```

This matches the requirements:

```
[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] --> [A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}   (1)
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] --> [0-9]{6}           (2)
[A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]     --> [A-Z]-[0-9]{4}     (3)
```

Answer (score 2):

The solutions below assume each line is an entry, and each entry is made up of fields delimited by a forward slash (/) character.

```
awk -F/ '$3~/[[:digit:]]{4}$/' filename
```

Awk is pretty efficient at it.

Comment: for some reason, none of these seem to really be working correctly.  But I found that this does:  grep -E '[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}|[A-Z]-[0-9]{4}'

Comment: @MikeQ What about it isn't working? Using a test file with the sample input you provided, I get the results you want...

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I was on my phone when I accidently downvoted your answer. I had to edit your answer to take it back. Apologies for that and +1 to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

[grep](/questions/tagged/grep) is the tool you are looking for:

```
grep '[0-9]\{4\}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This awk command checks for the ID contains letter number combination. If it's there, then it prints then corresponding line.

```
$ awk -F/ '$3~/[A-Z-]*[0-9][A-Z0-9]*/ {print}' file
    "111/S/H0110//Jake, Greenfield ServiceRequest/bin/ksh"
    "740/S/H5155//Jake, Greenfield/bin/ksh"
```

If you want only the numbers in the ID field then try this command,

```
$ awk -F/ '$3~/[A-Z-]*[0-9][A-Z0-9]*/ { gsub (/[A-Z-]/,"",$3); print $3}' file
0110
5155
```